# confusion on how to remove an HTML dropdown item element

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I am attempting to create a dynamic menu based upon user login status on a webpage.  Here is the code on the HTML page (Bootstrap 4):

```
     <div class="dropdown" id="account_info">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-elegant" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-user-circle"></i>  User</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" id="drop_down">

      </div>
     </div>
```

And the code to create a "Login" link or delete that link if the user is already 'signed in':

```
var _status = vitals.dataset.user;  //retrieve passed 'cookie' information...
var _log_status = sessionStorage.getItem("logged");

  if (_status != "none") {
   if ((_log_status === null) || (_log_status === "undefined")) { 
   elem = document.getElementById("account_in");
   elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);  //remove 'login' item
   sessionStorage.setItem("logged", "login"); 
   }  //user has 'signed in' for the initial time...
  } else {
  elem_set = document.createElement("a");
  elem_set.className = "drop-down-item";
  elem_set.id = "account_in";
  elem_set.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Login"));
  document.getElementById("drop_down").appendChild(elem_set); 
  }  //"user" cookie has passed...OR NOT...
```

If the user is not 'signed in', the code to create the "Login" link in the dropdown menu works fine (in the 'else' statement).  However an error is thrown when the user is 'signed in'. The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null" in the line that reads "elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem)".

I do not understand why the id for "account_in" is reported as 'null', since I create that element attribute...or is this error referring to something else?  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error means `elem` is null, which means the previous line did not find an element with the given id.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am aware of that. My confusion is as to why?  I set the 'ID' of the element when I created the menu dropdown list item...therefore why is it null?

Comment: I think there is an error in the logic. I don't fully nderstand what you're doing with the cookie and sessionStorage, but I think you may be trying to remove the element before you create it. Thus it doesn't exist (yet). One solution is to preface the `.removeChild` line with `if (elem)` but I would carefully examine the logic in the `if ((_log_status ...` line.

Comment: I am using the sessionStorage to record if the user had previously been 'signed in' or not.  Based upon that I would need to potentially add or remove menu dropdown items.

Comment: If I place the following after the 'Login' ('else' statement) creation I see the value is "DIV"...var x = document.getElementById("account_in").parentNode.nodeName;
console.log("account_in parent node: " + x);    I am assuming since a value of "DIV" is reported then the 'parentnode' and 'account_in' do in fact exist.  Could this information be lost upon a new page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a snippit below so I could actually run your code. I don't have the vitals library so I commented that out and just used a static value. Also this wouldn't let me use sessionStorage so I again used a static value.

There was an error comparing `_log_status === "undefined"` - I'm pretty sure you meant `typeof _log_status === "undefined"`

I also added the if statement I described in a comment.

If this still isn't what you need, please add a runnable snippit to your question above.

```js
var _status = 'Pangit'; //vitals.dataset.user;  //retrieve passed 'cookie' information...
var _log_status;  //sessionStorage.getItem("logged");

if (_status != "none") {
  if ((_log_status === null) || (typeof _log_status === "undefined")) { 
    elem = document.getElementById("account_in");
    
    // if _status != none and _log_status is undefined, elem will not exist
    if (elem) { 
      elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);  //remove 'login' item
    }

    //sessionStorage.setItem("logged", "login"); 
  }  //user has 'signed in' for the initial time...
} else {
  elem_set = document.createElement("a");
  elem_set.className = "drop-down-item";
  elem_set.id = "account_in";
  elem_set.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Login"));
  document.getElementById("drop_down").appendChild(elem_set); 
}  //"user" cookie has passed...OR NOT...
```

```html
     <div class="dropdown" id="account_info">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-elegant" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-user-circle"></i>  User</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" id="drop_down">

      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post.  I have replaced all my code with that you have attached.  I am able to run without any errors.  However I am confused by this statement you included, "if _status != none and _log_status is undefined, elem will not exist"...If I go to the page the first time, the "Login" item is created in the dropdown.  If I then go to log in (successfully) and return to the page...the "elem = document.getElementById("account_in")" statement SHOULD equate to 'true' (since that ID was created in the 'else' routine on the first page view)'...why does it not???

Comment: It seems that each visit to the page 'resets' to an initial state, therefore I should be able to simply create needed dropdown menu items dependent only on the user's login status....correct?  I was under the impression that once I created an element in the dropdown menu I would then need to delete it when the user status changed...